# Attaching objects to the surface of another object before modifying

Tags: modifiers, transforms

I'm modelling a creature that has a row of spines down its back. The creature's body and spines have been made as separate parts, and I've modelled the creature in a neutral pose with its spine and tail dead straight so that I can use symmetry tools. Now, I'm using a simple bezier curve modifier to transform that into the pose I want - the creature is long and narrow, with a long snakelike tail, so this seemed the most natural way, and far less effort than an armature given that I don't want to animate it.

Here's a spine on its back in neutral pose:
[image: spine on back, neutral pose]

How can I attach the spines to the creature's back so that they will remain attached after the curve modifier?

I tried the obvious approach of using Ctrl+J to join them into the mesh, but this results in the spines being deformed and warped by the curve modifier, which is not what I want. I just want them to pick a spot on the surface, and follow it.

Here's what happens when I Ctrl+J the spine onto the creature:

[image: distorted spine after joining]

The bezier curve modifier has distorted the spine, as indicated.

Comment: If you include a screenshot of the situation it will be much clearer. By any means, before joinin meshes, you have to have all modifiers applied. So, the Ctrl+J action should be the last action you have taken. First, apply the top-most modifier, then repeat until no modifier remains. Then you can safely join meshes.

Comment: I can't apply the modifiers before applying the curve modifier, because the whole point is to be able to add the spines to the creature when it's in a straight, symmetrical pose, and then use the curve modifier to pose it, which seems much less work than using a tonne of bendy bones amd having to mess with weight painting.